# Switch between the login view and the dashboard view does't working after user logged in

Tags: ios, swift

```
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
                    
                    let dashboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DashboardViewController")
         (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.changeRootViewController(_vc: dashboard)
                }
```

UIApplication.shared.delegate
appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = dashboard

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    if let loggedUsername = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user"){
        
        let dashboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DashboardViewController")
        window?.rootViewController = dashboard
    }
    else{
        let loginView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController")
        window?.rootViewController = loginView
    }

    
    
    
    
}
```

I have also tried this but it did not work too

```
func changeRootViewController( _vc: UIViewController, animted: Bool = true){
    guard let window = self.window else {
        return
    }
    
    UIView.transition(with: window,
                      duration: 0.5,
                      options: .transitionCurlDown,
                      animations: nil,
                      completion: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65211959/6920041

Comment: is it solve your probelm? any help?

Comment: I get this Exeption  
Exception NSException * "[<NSUserDefaults> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isLogin."
name __NSCFConstantString * "NSUnknownKeyException" 0x00007fff801e7c90
reason __NSCFString * "[<NSUserDefaults 0x7fff86b8bd58> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isLogin." 0x0000600000238240
NSMutableString NSMutableString 
userInfo __NSDictionaryI * 2 key/value pairs
[0] (null) "NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey" : (no summary) 
[1] (null) "NSUnknownUserInfoKey" : "isLogin"

Comment: please send me your code

Comment: please add  if USERDEFAULT.value(forKey:"isLogin") != nil{ } this condation after Login api call successfuly staus 1 than set USERDEFAULT.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")

Comment: Please check my answer. let's try to easy

Answer (score 0):

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationC: UINavigationController?
private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    if let loggedUsername = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user"){
        let dashboardvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardvc)
    } else{
        let loginvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginvc)
    }
    self.navigationC!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    self.window?.clipsToBounds = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    Self.shared = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as?NSDictionary
            
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let accessToken = parseJSON["token"] as? String
                let username = parseJSON["user"] as? String
                
                _ = UserDefaults(suiteName: username)
                
                print("Access token: \(String(accessToken!))")
                
                let saveAccessToken: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(accessToken!, forKey: "accessToken")
                
                let saveUsername: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(username!, forKey: "username")
                
                if(accessToken?.isEmpty)! {
                    self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Inloggen is niet success, probeer later")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                    USERDEFAULT.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")

                    let dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController

                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: Please check my answer and update SceneDelegate in file

Answer (score 0):

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationC : UINavigationController?
private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    if UserDefaults.value(forKey: "isLogin") != nil {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dashboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboard)
    }else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let loginPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as!ViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginPage)

    }

    self.navigationC!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    self.window?.clipsToBounds = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationC

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    Self.shared = self

    
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do{
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as?NSDictionary

```
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let accessToken = parseJSON["token"] as? String
                let username = parseJSON["user"] as? String
                
                _ = UserDefaults(suiteName: username)
                
                print("Access token: \(String(accessToken!))")
                
                let saveAccessToken: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(accessToken!, forKey: "accessToken")
                
                let saveUsername: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(username!, forKey: "username")
                
                if(accessToken?.isEmpty)! {
                    self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Inloggen is niet success, probeer later")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    
                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                    
                    
                    let dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
                                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
                }
                
            }
        }catch{
            self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myactivit)
            self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Probeer later")
            return
            
        }
    }
```

\ this my SceneDelegate file

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationC : UINavigationController?
private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    if UserDefaults.value(forKey: "isLogin") != nil {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dashboard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboard)
    }else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let loginPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as!ViewController
        self.navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginPage)

    }

    self.navigationC!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    self.window?.clipsToBounds = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationC

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    Self.shared = self

    
    
    
    
}

func changeRootViewController( _vc: UIViewController, animted: Bool = true){
    guard let window = self.window else {
        return
    }

    UIView.transition(with: window,
                      duration: 0.5,
                      options: .transitionCurlDown,
                      animations: nil,
                      completion: nil)

}
```

\ I get this error

Exception   NSException *   "[<NSUserDefaults 0x7fff86b8bd58> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isLogin."    0x0000600001abc930
name    __NSCFConstantString *  "NSUnknownKeyException" 0x00007fff801e7c90
reason  __NSCFString *  "[<NSUserDefaults 0x7fff86b8bd58> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isLogin."    0x00006000026e8090
userInfo    __NSDictionaryI *   2 key/value pairs   0x00006000001a4d40
reserved    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x00006000014c0ac0

Comment: which class in define let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "isLogin") ????

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let dashboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
                        
   self.view.window?.rootViewController = dashboard
   self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()                            
}
```